# running file, getting StackOverflowError

Tags: java, netbeans, stack-overflow

I'm working on a small application that handles finances and so on. The development environment i use is netbeans.

I have a methods-class (called Methoden) where I have stored all the methods, a data-class and the frame-class (called Fenster1)

To get some input I defined a method in the method-class and tried to access it with

```
Methoden m = new Methoden();
...
buttonAction {
   m.getInput();
}
```

Code is fine, no errors at all. But when I try to start the application it takes a while and then this error appears:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
>   at sun.awt.Win32GraphicsConfig.getBounds(Native Method)
>   at sun.awt.Win32GraphicsConfig.getBounds(Win32GraphicsConfig.java:222)
>   at java.awt.Window.init(Window.java:496)
>   at java.awt.Window.(Window.java:535)
>   at java.awt.Frame.(Frame.java:420)
>   at java.awt.Frame.(Frame.java:385)
>   at javax.swing.JFrame.(JFrame.java:180)
>   at haushaltsbuch.Fenster1.(Fenster1.java:19)
>   at haushaltsbuch.Methoden.(Methoden.java:16)

Now: how can I fix this error to make everything running fine?

---

seems resolved.

in Fenster1 there was `Methoden m = new Methoden();` 
while in Methoden there was `Fenster1 f = new Fenster1();`

Comment: Probably you've got recursion going on -- a method calling itself, or perhaps more likely a class creating itself over and over again. Perhaps the JFrame creates the Method class which creates the JFrame which creates the Method,... etc... Not my down-vote, but you haven't posted enough to really allow us to do more than guess. You should in the least post the code around the lines which cause the error stacktrace that occurs.

Comment: Again, please give more information.

Comment: that seems to have been the issue. one class was creating a reference object to the other and the other did the same vice-versa.

But how can i access e.g. buttons from the one class and methods from the other class without ending up in recursion?

Comment: You  pass in references of one object to the other using setter methods or constructor parameters. You don't create the object afresh each time. Give Fenster1 a method `public void setMethoden(Methoden m)` and in that method set a Methoden field to the parameter.

Comment: im quite new to java and i cant cope with your explanation, its a bit to complicated for me^^
is there any explanation that shows how this setMethoden stuff works or can you explain it in more detail? thanks :)

Comment: Do you understand setter and getter methods, also known as [mutator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method) and accessor methods? You should understand basic Java before attempting complex GUI stuff.

Comment: hm.. ill take a closer look on that. can i somehow give you reputation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A stack overflow exception means (usually) that a function recursively calls itself. I would suspect Methoden#getInput() does this.